# How to Initialize values of 2D array in constructor?

Tags: constructor

I have a problem in initializing values of 2D array in a constructor. I am creating a Tic-Tac-Toe game. I am to required to initialize values from the 2D array so that the values is displayed on the board. I am not sure on the way to do it.

```
I used a nested for loop to initialize values but it didn't work.  

class TicTacToe
{
private:
    char matrix[3][3];
public:
TicTacToe();
TicTacToe(char matrix[3][3]);


TicTacToe::TicTacToe(char matrix[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


I expect the values from the array to be displayed on the board.
```